# Android:nonstop Back ground service

Tags: android

I have started a  service from my application and from that service a worker thread is started .I want my service  to run   even application goes background  and until  the user  kills/exits the application.

But some cases my service got killed due to low memory  ,then used  sticky service or making the app to foreground  to restart the service.

My issue is I dont want to lose the data  between  service ending and restarting time ,so  is it possible to start another thread  from service ondestroy  method, but in this case how we can control that thread.

Please let  me know is it the right approach  ,and is this usecase achievable

Answer (score 1):

> I want my service to run even application goes background and until the user kills/exits the application.

This is not possible. The user can always get rid of your app, via Force Close in Settings, or via some device's version of the recent-tasks list.

> But some cases my service got killed due to low memory

No, your process is terminated for low memory.

> My issue is I dont want to lose the data between service ending and restarting time ,so is it possible to start another thread from service ondestroy method

No, because your process is being terminated.

> Please let me know is it the right approach

Probably not. Very few apps need a service that runs constantly, which is why Android, and its users, go to great lengths to control such services. I would recommend that you try to find some solution to whatever your problem is that does not need a service running constantly.

Comment: Thanks for valuable comments..the issue is I want to collect location details in predefined time interval in seconds and this interval is very short.